# How can I search contacts and run a report of contacts with no activity

Tags: activity

I'm struggling to find a list of conatcts with no activity records, could someone help me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Use search builder to search for all contacts with the activity field: activity date of "not null" and add them to new group "has activities". Use the include/exclude custom search to find any contact not in the "has activities group and add them to a new group "no activities".

Comment: That's pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

You could export a list of contacts, export a list of activities, and then using vlookup() in excel find the rows in the contact list that do not appear in the list of activities.

See e.g. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3124-excel-compare-two-columns-for-missing-values.html#formula where it says "Compare two columns for (highlighting) missing values with formulas"